# Facebook Connect - publishUserAction template problem

Tags: facebook

I am getting the error: "The template data provided doesn't cover the entire token set needed to publish the story"

My template is:  "`{*actor*} just scored {*points*} points.`"

My code is:

```
NSMutableDictionary* feedStoryParams = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[feedStoryParams setObject:<MyBundle ID> forKey:@"template_bundle_id"];
[feedStoryParams setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"points\":\"42\""] forKey:@"template_data"]; 

[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"Feed.publishUserAction" params:feedStoryParams];
```

This is after the user logs into Facebook in my iPhone app (and I checked to make sure the session ID is there).

I have tested also tested it by removing the "points" entry from the dictionary, and it then gives me the correct error saying that the {points} entry is missing and is required by the template "`{*actor*} just scored {*points*} points.`". So I also know that the template bundle ID is correct.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Putting everything in an explicit JSON hash fixed it.  Try replacing

```
[feedStoryParams setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"points\":\"42\""] forKey:@"template_data"];
```

with

```
[feedStoryParams setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"points\":\"42\"}"] forKey:@"template_data"];
```

Comment: Thanks!!  It is always something simple, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Should 'actor' appear somewhere in the template_data?

Comment: No, it is filled in automatically by Facebook based on the session info